# Chiral transformations

Tags: field-theory, group-theory, chirality

In Gerard Ecker's book 'Chiral Perturbation Theory' he states that if we have a symmetry group $G$, an element $g \in G$ induces a transformation in $u \in G/H$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
u(\phi) \rightarrow g u(\phi)  = u(\phi') h(g, \phi').\
\end{equation}
where $h$ is an element of $H$, a subgroup of $G$.

In chiral theory we have $G=SU(3)_L \times SU(3)_R$ and $H=SU(3)_V$ as the unbroken/conserved subgroup. Ecker states that in the case of chiral symmetries, we can write
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
u(\phi') = R u(\phi) h(g, \phi)^{-1}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
u(\phi') =  h(g, \phi) u(\phi) L^\dagger
\end{equation}
with a standard choice of coset representatives in equation (1). Where $L$ and $R$ are the left and right hand transformations related to $SU(3)_L$ and $SU(3)_R$, so $g=(L,R) \in G$.

These equations are what lead to the scalar field transformations $\Sigma \rightarrow R \Sigma L^\dagger$. But I cannot understand how to go from (1) to (2) and (3).

Could someone please explain how to rewrite the group transformation (1) in terms of right and left-handed transformations?

Comment: Spinors? When did you last mentioned spinors? How do you number your equations w.r.t. numbering in, e.g., [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9501357.pdf)? Are all your primed variable "ducks" in a row?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Spinors was a mistake, I meant transformations. In the paper you linked you can look at eqs. 2.4 and 2.6. I don't understand your comment about the primed variables, I'm sorry. But they are transformations of the $\phi$ field under the group transformation g. By the way, I already managed to solve the issue. Might write an answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take $g =R \in SU(3)_R$ and apply it to eq.(1), such that
\begin{equation}
R u(\phi)  = u(\phi') h(R, \phi')
\end{equation}
and then we get eq.(2)\begin{equation}
u(\phi') = R u(\phi)h(R, \phi')^{-1}.
\end{equation}

To get eq.(3) we apply a parity operation:
and then we get eq.(2)\begin{align}
Pu(\phi')P = PR u(\phi)h(R, \phi')^{-1}P.\\
u(\phi')^\dagger = L u(\phi)^\dagger h(L, \phi')^{-1}.\\
u(\phi') = h(L, \phi')u(\phi) L^\dagger.\\
\end{align}